# Caching in WebSockets

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, webforms, websocket

Is it possible to use classes from the System.Web.Caching namespace with an ASP.NET application which uses WebSockets?

I have decided to use open source WebSocket (SuperSocket) with use of ASP.net 4.0. Is System.Web.Caching.Cache use for page load event (for example for WebServices)? As in WebSocket you do not need to load the page to retrieve the data! For that reason I do not think the System.Web.Caching.Cache will work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you can't access [`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) then use [`System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache)

Enough caching options for anyone's needs.

[Maybe it's a British thing, but isn't it meant to be cacheing?]

Comment: thanks for commnet but need to know is it possible for WebScoket